# How granular should a domain event be?

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs, event-sourcing

I am wondering how granular should a domain event be?

For example I have something simple, like changing the firstName, the secondName and the email address on a profile page. Should I have 3 different domain events or just a single one?

By coarse grained domain events when I add a new feature, I have to create a new version of the event, so I have to add a new event type, or store event versions in the event storage. By fine grained domain events I don't have these problems, but I have too many small classes. What do you think, what is the best practice in this case?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What's the problem with many classes? Really, why so many devs are afraid of having too many classes? You define as many classes as needed.

A domain event signals that the domain changed in a certain way. It should contain all the relevant information and it should be taken into consideration the fact that an event is also a DTO. You want clear events but it's up to the developer to decide how granular or generic an event is.

Size is not a concern, however if your event 'weights' 1 MB maybe you have a problem. And the number of classes is not a domain event design criteria.

Comment: Thanks, granular was the word I was looking for.

Comment: "What's the problem with many classes?" - defining a class for each property change is a bit strange concept for me... I don't know, it's a gut feeling... :D Btw. having small classes with 3-4 property is okay, but having a DTO with a single property is not okay for me.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? What would you do by the profile change example I gave?

Comment: You don't define a class for each property change, you define a class for each domain change which can be 1 or many properties

Comment: How do you decide that you have one or many domain changes inside a command, and how many properties should they have? ;-)

Comment: +1 for arguing against devs being afraid of many classes (and quoting their "gut feeling" for it...)

Comment: I agree with you @MikeSW. I'm facing this situation now and to me it seems more logical to have fine-grained events. The thing to consider IMO is that the event class should contain all the details of what has happened, no more, no less. If we consider "persons", then we could define a PersonChangedEvent containing n fields or a PersonNameChangedEvent. If we define a PersonChangedEvent containing many fields then it might be problematic to actually know which exact field(s) has/have been changed. Thus so far I'm more in favor of PersonNameChanged. But indeed it all "depends" :)

Answer (score 12):

I can agree with MikeSW's answer, but applying SRP during the modeling, you can end up with small classes, which is not a problem at all.

According to [Greg Young](https://skillsmatter.com/skillscasts/1354-greg-young-cqrs-event-sourcing-the-business-perspective) the domain events should always express something that the user does from a business perspective. For example if the user has 2 reasons to change her phone number `PhoneNumberChanged`, and this information can be important from a business perspective, then we should create 2 event types `PhoneNumberMigrated`, `PhoneNumberCorrected` to store technically the same data. This clearly violates DRY, but that is not a problem, because SRP can override DRY in these cases as it does by sharing aggregates and their properties (most frequently the aggregate id) between multiple bounded contexts.

In my example:

> I have something simple, like changing the firstName, the
>   secondName and the email address on a profile page.

We should ask the following: why would the user want that, has it any importance from the perspective of our business?

- her account was stolen (security, not business issue)
- she moved to another email address
- she got married
- she hated her previous name
- she gave the account to somebody else on purpose
- etc...

Well, if we have dating agency services then logging divorces can have probably a business importance. So if this information is really important, then we should put that it into the domain model, and create an `UserProbablyDivorced` event. If none of them are important, then we can simple say, that she just wanted to change her profile page, we don't care why, so I think in that case both `UserProfileChanged` or `UserSecondNameChanged` events can be acceptable.

The domain events can be in 1:1 and in 1:n relation with the commands. By 1:1 relation they name is usually the same as of the commands, but in a past tense. For example `ChangeUserProfile -> UserProfileChanged`. By 1:n relation we usually split up the behavior which the command represents into a series of smaller domain events.

So to summarize, it is the domain developer's decision how granular the domain events should be, but it should by clearly influenced from a business perspective and not just from a modeling a data schema perspective. But I think this is evident, because we are modeling business and not just data structure.

Comment: You are making a little mess of things. CQRS is unrelated to Event Sourcing (ES), but they are used together. You don't design a domain event for ES because you aren't always using ES, and I disagree that an event should always express user intent. Events capture _Domain_ changes regardless what triggered them. PhoneNumberMigrated and PhoneNumberCorrected are from the Domain point of view not the user's. A domain expert isn't a coder, (s)he wouldn't have a clue what commands/events are. The developer would decide on the structure of an event based on the discussion with a domain expert

Comment: Deciding everything before a single line of code is written surely smells waterfally and it's a too rigid approach IMO. You know, the developer is not that business clueless monkey who just churns out code. The dev MUST understand the domain before coding, but the dev does the modelling not the domain expert (unless they are the same person). So I must say that the developer has everything to do with it.

Comment: Downvoted for "In DDD and CQRS there can be places where these laws cannot be always valid." this is simply not true. Also DDD, ES and CQRS are distinct things. "Designing an application with CQRS" doesn't really make sense as a statement.

Comment: @Roysvork Feel free to add your answer.

Comment: @MikeSW I did not mean waterfall. You can still have release early, release often, just always design first what command, queries and domain events should your new feature have, and implement only after you have a complete model of that.

Comment: @MikeSW I think non of use is right about who does the modeling, because according to this: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/167425/should-a-domain-expert-make-class-diagrams , the domain expert provides a basic model, which is usually cleared up by devs, so it is a team work. You were right, about that part that the domain expert should not write the code, so that part is okay.

Comment: @MikeSW It seems I confused domain developers with domain experts. Poor choice of words... :S

Comment: I'll edit the answer to contain only the user intent part of the story.